# Creating parsers using flex/bison

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

Hi I'm need to create a parser to parse search engine advanced query languages:
For instance: “food” language:es

I want to use Flex and Bison but I've never used them. I was wondering if anyone could point me to a good tutorial online, then it would be really helpful. I've been looking online but I didn't find anything useful.

Also, If anyone can provide any sample flex/bison code, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: [dinosaur.compilertools.net](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/)

Comment: You should make a conscious choice of tool, given good background.  A good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler

Comment: Seriously? You can parse such query languages with `sscanf` and `strtok`.

Comment: what does sscanf do? Can you give some examples? THanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you have been unable to find good tutorial's online, as the use of flex and bison and similar compiling tools are used in large numbers of computer science university courses world wide. As many people are learning them there are a large number of resources available. You must not have been using the right search terms. There are also numerous helpful tutorial videos on YouTube (including mine).

When I searched, this one came are the first result: http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html

The page suggested by @Bart Kiers http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/ is good too.